# Finding Big O of a nest for loop

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

```
for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
  for (j=0;j<i*i;j++)
    x++
```

Would the big O be **O(n^3)**? I'm just confused about how the i's relate to the **n**.

Comment: yes, it will be O(n^3)

Answer (score 0):

The required math (summation) is:

```
0 + 1 + 4 + 9 + ... + n * n = n**3 / 3 + n**2 / 2 + n / 6 = O(n**3)
```

So, you're right: it's **O(n**3)**; moreover

```
  0 + 1 + ... + n**k = O(n**(k + 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Methodically, to proceed using Sigma notation like below, would get you where you need to go:

[image]